# How to use ajax to display php code when button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have this code here,

```
<!-- Ajax!--><button type="button">Click Me</button>
        <p></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'random.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(".mainContainer").text(data);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

but this script doesn't show the markup, just the text.

The php file echo's some HTML Markup such as

```
<img>
<p>
```

But the script I have is showing the text WITH the markup but I want the script to show the script WITHOUT the markup (using it).

I'm sure it has to do with the

```
$(".mainContainer").text(data);
```

What do I change the "text" to?

First time here at StackOverflow, go easy on me!

Comment: try like this `$(".mainContainer").html(data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `html`:

```
$(".mainContainer").html(data);
```

You can read more about `html` function in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** or **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** for setting html content.

```
$(".mainContainer").html(data);
```

or

```
$(".mainContainer")[0].innerHTML=data;
```

> **[text(text)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text)** : We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), **does not interpret the string as HTML**.( Taken from : http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text )